# Database query in django

Tags: python, django

I am creating a simple quiz app using django. When a user submits the answer for a question, the answer is checked using the correct answer present in database.

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render,get_object_or_404
from .models import question
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect, HttpResponse
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse

def detail(request, question_id):
    ques = get_object_or_404(question, pk=question_id)
    return render(request, 'detail.html', {'ques': ques})

def index(request):
    questions = question.objects.all()
    return render(request,"question.html",{"questions":questions})

def vote(request,question_id):
    p = get_object_or_404(question, pk=question_id)
    selected_choice = p.choice_set.get(pk = request.POST['choice'])
    print selected_choice,p.answer_text
    if(selected_choice == p.answer_text):
        print "yes"
    x = int(question_id) + 1
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('detail', args=(str(x))))
```

The vote function is called after user clicks the submit button. The check is performed here. When I print selected_choice and p.answer_text, they show correct values. But when I compare them using equal operator, it doesn't return true even when both are same.

```
models.py
    from django.db import models

    class question(models.Model):
        question_text = models.CharField(max_length = 400)
        answer_text = models.CharField(max_length = 400,default = "name")
        def __unicode__(self):
            return self.question_text,self.answer_text
    class choice(models.Model):
        question = models.ForeignKey(question)
        choice_text = models.CharField(max_length = 200)
        def __unicode__(self):
            return self.choice_text
```

Comment: I think you want to compare `p.answer_text` and `selected_choice.choice_text`.

Comment: That worked. Thanks :)